# Auto add history table into view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a history view which has tables for 2011, 2012, ...., 2017.

When the time passes to 2018, we need to add the 2018 table into the view.

The definition for the table is like:

```
create view v_a
as 
   select id, name, 1 from 2011
   union all
   select id, name, 1 from 2012
   ....
   union all
   select id, name, 1 from 2017
```

I want the view changing to

```
create view v_a
as 
    select id, name, 1 from 2011
    union all
    select id, name, 1 from 2012
    ....
    union all
    select id, name, 1 from 2017
    union all
    select id, name, 1 from 2018
```

How can I implement it by using an automatic script?

Comment: The traditional answer is to create history tables good until your retirement/quit date and add them to the view now. Not exactly a "best practice".

Comment: @WisonHe welcome to Stackoverflow, feel free to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to read more about asking question, accepting answers, and other features. And to Get your "Informed" badge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an SQL Agent Job that run the following SQL command (build command dynamically):

```
DECLARE @intCurrentYEAR as INTEGER
DECLARE @intInitialYEAR as INTEGER
DECLARE @strQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @intCurrentYEAR = YEAR(GETDATE())
SET @intInitialYEAR = 2011


SET @strQuery = 'Alter view v_a as select id,name,1 from [' + CAST (@intInitialYEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + '] '

SET @intInitialYEAR = @intInitialYEAR + 1

WHILE @intInitialYEAR <= @intCurrentYEAR
BEGIN

SET @strQuery = @strQuery + ' UNION ALL select id,name,1 from [' + CAST (@intInitialYEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + '] '

SET @intInitialYEAR = @intInitialYEAR + 1


END

EXEC(@strQuery)
```

Comment: tks. you saved me a lot of ime

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a SQL Agent Job with a "run once" schedule? Or create a windows task scheduler task that kicks off a batch script that calls a PowerShell script that updates the database.

Comment: yes. I can set up job to call the script. but I have no idea about how to realize the logic ?

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem you're right, i provided an SQL query that can be executed from SQL agent job. take a look